# Qt 5: const char * QString cast

Tags: c++, qt4, qt5, qstring, qtcore

In Qt 4 it is possible to automatically cast a QString to a "const char *", e.g. I could pass a QString to a function that expected a "const char *".

```
void myFunction(const char *parameter);

QString myString;
myFunction(myString); //works in QT4
```

In Qt 5 I would however get an "error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'QString' to 'const char *'" (that is the Visual C++ 2008 compiler, other compilers would throw something similar). If I understand the documentation correctly, it is because the Qt 3 compatibility layer is not included anymore in QT5.

Of course, I could change the function call from

```
myFunction(myString);
```

to

```
myFunction(myString.toLatin1().data());
```

However, I have a huge code base that compiles fine with Qt 4 and I would really like to have my old code compile with Qt 5 without modifying it. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a macro or inline function for your purpose to minimize the changes, but since that would also require a grep alike operation, there is not much difference.

```
#define QString2charp(myString) myString.toLatin1().data()
```

or

```
inline char* QString2charp (const QString &myString)
{
    return myString.toLatin1().data();
}
```

and then:

```
myFunction(QString2charp(myString));
```

### BUT

of course, in an ideal world, it would be nice if your "myFunction" could get an overload expecting a `QString` argument.

```
void myFunction(const char *parameter);
void myFunction(QString parameter);
```

and then the overload would be implemented like this:

```
void myFunction(const QString &parameter)
{
    myFunction(myString.toLatin1().data());
}
```

of course, this would require the constructor being explicit so that no implicit conversion can happen, otherwise the compiler will complain about ambiguity in presence of both when trying to pass `const char*`, but if you always use QString, it should just work with Qt 5.

This is somewhat equal to rewriting the original function to a different signature expecting `QString` though because unfortunately the corresponding constructor is not explicit. I imagine that was not changed in Qt 5 for compatibility as it would have broken too much code.

As you can see, you do not need to change anything in your code this way, other than adding a one-liner overload. It is neat, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You could either

- Change the signature of your function to `MyFunction( const QString & parameter )` (of course that works only if you don't need the one that takes `char *` any more)
- Overload `MyFunction`:

  ```
  void myFunction(const char *parameter); //this is your normal function
  void myFunction( const QString & parameter )
  {
      char * c_str = nullptr;
      <convert parameter to char * in any way that suits you>
      myFunction( c_str );
  }
  ```
- If the above is impossible for some reason, the best approach is probably to write a similar wrapper:

  ```
  void MyFunctionWrapper( const QString & parameter )
  {
      <same as above>
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It is no longer possible to cast  `QString` to `const char*` in >= Qt 5, because `QString` is `UTF-16` and no longer has an entry for caching the result of converting to ASCII.

The way to achieve your aim is
a) Add overloads to the functions expecting `const char*` which can handle `QString`s,
b) Add the explicit conversion code to the call-site, or
c) Go to some `char`-based string, like `std::string`.

None of those fulfill your aim of nearly no changes though.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on QT forum

```
const QByteArray byteArray = mytext = textBox.text().toUtf8();
const char *mytext = byteArray.constData();
```

This resolved my issue